# Qt, POP3 and SSL?

Tags: c++, ssl, network-programming, qt-creator, pop3

If Gmail is using SSL does this mean that I have to implement the algorithms for encrypting and decrypting all the traffic by myself in order to download the mail?

If so, is there a fast workaround for doing this ?

I should mention that I'm making a POP3 client from scratch in Qt Creator and I want to implement all the communication by myself.

Comment: Is this project you're doing open-source? I'd be interested to take a look at the code, because I've been thinking of implementing exactly the same thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to implement encryption algorithms by yourself.
Qt includes SSL support under QSsl namespace, which was introduced in Qt 4.3.
You should consider looking under QSsl namespace for required classes and enumerations.